# how to assign base class object to a derived class object?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Assuming I have a base class A and publicly derived class B, how should I assign A object to the A base class subobject of B?

```
class A {...};
class B : public A {...};
A a(..);
B b(..);
static_cast<A&>(b) = a; ???
```

Is that doable without writing assignement operator for B? Are there any potential problems with casting b to A&? Is that standard conformant?

Comment: That's a good question- what would the semantics under such assignment be?

Comment: There are several usage in the MS VC ATL library.

Comment: Very common with method only class inheriting data only struct, like database accessor classes.

Comment: +1 Plain simple question but has very good reminding point for long time C++ programmers with shallow Object Orient Programing experience.

Comment: Another way to write the same is `b.A::operator=(a);`.
Both are not intuitive but very usefull

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Writing another answer to demonstrate why and how assign a base class object to a derived class object.

```
struct TimeMachineThing_Data {
..
..
};

class TimeMachineThing : private TimeMachineThing_Data
{
    static std::stack<TimeMachineThing_Data> m_stateHistory;

    void SaveState() {
        m_stateHistory.push_back( static_cast<TimeMachineThing_Data&>(*this) );
    }

    void RestoreState() {
        static_cast<TimeMachineThing_Data&>(*this) = m_stateHistory.front();
        m_stateHistory.pop_front();
    }
};
```

It's very useful and fully legitimate.

(Here is private inheritance, so only internally TimeMachineThing IS-A TimeMachinetime_Data)

---

Another one.

```
struct StructWithHundresField {
  string title;
  string author;
  ...

  StructWithHundresField() {
    ...
  }
};

class EasyResetClass : public StructWithHundresField {
  int not_reset_this_attriute;
public:
  void ResetToInitialStateAtAnyTime() {
    static_cast<StructWithHundresField&>(*this) = StructWithHundresField();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is rarely a useful pattern, though.  Composition should be preferred to private inheritance wherever possible.

Answer (score 6):

That's a really bad idea.  A is the base, B is a derived type.  By casting B to an A, you are now using A's assignment operator, which isn't going to touch any of the extra derived data.  At the end of that assignment, `b` is still considered to be of type `B`, even though it now contains an `A`.  This is the opposite of the way inheritance is meant to be used.

Changing the line to `b = reinterpret_cast<B&>(a);` would be even worse.  Then you would be pretending that `a` is a `B` when it's not, and you be reading invalid memory.

If you truly want to do this kind of assignment, you want:

```
class B : public A {
    B& operator= (const A& a) { ... }
};
```

Then you can write a function to copy the information from the `A`, and somehow deal with the extra information in the derived type `B`, plus this would allow you to simply write:

```
b = a;
```

Comment: "which isn't going to touch any of the extra derived data" - and if that is exactly what I want then how is that a bad idea?

Comment: It's a bad idea, because you're only assigning a portion of your data.  I.e. if `A` has members `p, q` and `B` adds member `r`, when you do the assignment `static_cast<A&>(b) = a;` you only assign `p,q`, and leave `r` untouched.  This is most likely not what you want, as it's basically an incomplete assignment.  So I could have worded it "This is usually a really bad idea, but if you understand the risks, here's how to do it."

Comment: I lost how to explain this.. It's so fundamental and basic aspect of object oriented programming. If B inherit A, B is A (with some added aspects).

Comment: yes, and it's those added aspects that matter here.  Instead of A and B, lets use `class Boss : public Employee`.  If you then do `boss1 = employee1;`, boss1 is now not really a boss anymore.  Definitely still an employee, but not a boss.

Comment: @Tim now feel like understand your reasoning. You probably mistaken assignment with allocation. One can not assign newly created A instance to B reference but one can change A portion of B any time any way.

Comment: I'm not confusing assignment with allocation.  I understand that the code works, and doesn't trample memory.  I'm saying this is a bad practice, as its results are probably not what you wanted.  As I said above, you can do the assignment, leaving the derived members data untouched... but is that really what you want?  If you want to set the derived members to a default (or interpolated) value, use the assignment operator above.  If you actually want to leave the derived members as-is, go ahead -- just be sure to understand what you're doing, and COMMENT IT for the sake of the maintainer.

Comment: @Tim then what can be the implementation code of above assignment operator? Something like "static_cast<A&>(*this) = a;" ??

Comment: @9dan:  `A::operator=(a);`  There is nothing wrong with calling the base class assignment operator from a derived class member function.

Comment: @James Wow, I didn't thought of that before. It'd be more strait and clear notation (but effectively doing the same).

Comment: I agree with @9dan, while it may be considered a bad practice in C++, it's a perfectly logical operation. As per @Tim's `Boss` and `Employee` example. If first make an `Employee joe;` and assign his values, and then use `joe` as a starting point to create `Boss bob` who is a boss (with several special boss characteristics) but as an employee he is the same damn guy as `joe`. Anyway, it makes sense to me. It does not violate the fundamental "is a" of inheritance. I wish something like the proposed operator was implicitly defined, but perhaps it's better to do it explicitly for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ (as with other OOP languages) inheritance establish Is-A relationship.

That is, if B publicly inherit A, B = A.

You always can cast B instance to A reference without any worry.

Comment: Makes sense. I was only worried about any potential problems with memory layout - I somehow can't find an argument why such assigments have to always work in C++.

Comment: -1: @ 9dan it's **FALSE**. In memory B shall be different than an A. So when doing B = A you only copy a slice of A to a B. Results are unforseable. **Polymorphism works through the usage of Pointers and of References only**

Comment: @Stephane What specific word or phrase is FALSE in my answer? If I intended to modify A potion of B's memory, really I could not predict result of the assignment? Did you misunderderstood type equality and data equality?

Comment: @9dan it's **false** when you write  "if B publicly inherit A, B = A." type and data are not equal in 99% of the common C++ everyday cases when "B publicly inherit".

Comment: @Stephane then How can you use inherited A's method with B instance ?? All A's method must include dynamic_cast thing for the future inheriance ?? Or Do we need static_cast before pass B instance to the function expecting A ??

Comment: @9dan... void func(A); and void func(A&); (or void func(A*);) behaves differently.  void func(A) will not keep the integrity of B objects. For example, if B has overriden virtual methods from A, they couldnt be called inside void func(A); on the contraty using void func(A&); will preserve the whole integrity of the B object, handled as an A.

Comment: @Stephane So we could use all of A's method with B instance right? And in A's view, B instances are the exactly same with the pure A instance right? That's the IS-A relationship I'm trying to explain.

Comment: to "use" ? For you "to use", is it to abtractly invoke or to really execute ? If by type you only mean abstract interface, then I may agree with you.

Comment: @9dan, I completely get where you are coming from, I'm with you lol. Thanks for clarifying the IS-A relationship over and over. I'm not sure why a couple people here seem to disagree.

Answer (score 2):

Think for a minute about whether this is a good idea.  Remember that if you have B subclassing A, then every B is an A but not every A is a B.  For example, every dog is a mammal, but not every mammal is a dog.  If you have a concrete B object, trying to set it to an A object isn't mathematically well-defined in most cases.  Moreover, in the world of C++, because you B object is statically typed as a B, you can never assign it an object of type A in a way that will make it stop being a B.  At best, you're going to overwrite just the A portion of the B object without changing any of the B-specific parts.

Answer (score 2):

Slicing assignment is safe only, if your base class is in
standard layout: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout . Better even, if your derived class is also standard layout.

In particular, your base class must not contain virtual methods or a virtual destructor, and all non-static data members must have the same access control (like `public` or `private`). Your base class may have a base class itself, and it may have data members, that are objects of other classes, but all those classes, that you that way inherit into your base class, must also be standard layout.

If your base class is standard layout, then there is nothing wrong with a slicing assignment to it, as that is guaranteed to only touch the data members of the base class. All other cases are unsafe, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need an assignment operator that specifically copies an A object to a B object.

In general, it's a good idea to have one any way when copying objects of the same type. But objects of different types make it even more important.

Answer (score 0):

`static_cast<TimeMachineThing_Data&>(*this) = m_stateHistory.front();` can be rewritten without the cast as `TimeMachineThing_Data & data = *this; data =  m_stateHistory.front();`.

Answer (score -1):

Everyone should know assignment is a covariant binary operator and therefore cannot work correctly with virtual functions. This is true for most binary operators, but assignment is special because it is part of the C++ language.

If you are using OO, your objects should be uncopyable and always represented by pointers. Uniqueness of object identity is the heart of OO: objects are not values, they *have* a unique value (their address).

If you are playing with values you should be using the appropriate concepts: functional programming (FP). That's closures (applicative objects), switches, templates, variants, and other stuff.

Try to get a solid understanding of each before mixing them. In general FP subsumes OO so is the general methodology: OO is a special case that in special circumstances delivers safe dynamic dispatch. OO dispatch is linear which means it handles an unbounded set of subtypes but it also applies only to properties (functions with one variant argument, namely the object) and can't work for anything higher order (functions with more than one variant argument). Assignment is just another 2-ary function, hence, it can't be dispatched with virtual functions.