# Assign to base class part of the object only

Tags: c#, inheritance, assignment-operator

When class D is derived from class B, how do I assign to the B part of it only?

In C++, I would do:

```
D d;
B b;
d.B::operator = (b);
```

What is the C# equivalent of this?

Comment: Do you mean the [base](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if

```
class B {}
class D : B {}
```

then `D` essentially **is** a `B` with added functionality. There is no 'part' of it that is `B`, it *is* a `B`.

So this is not possible in such as direct way as you are trying to do. You'd have to implement a function in `D` for it yourself, such as `void Merge(B b)` which assigns fields from `B` to the object's (`D`) relevant `base` fields.

Comment: I guess I have to learn object assignment is much different in C# - it always assigns reference to the object, not the object content.

Comment: @Suma That's only the case for classes, not structs.  In the case of value types (which includes user defined structs) variables represent the value of the object itself, just as they do in C++.  The difference is that in C# structs cannot inherit from anything other than one common base type, which is why C# prevents slicing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent of slicing in C#.  You would need to manually create an instance of the base class and copy over the relevant properties.  If the base class had a non-virtual clone method (or copy constructor) then you could use that, but you can't use slicing as in C++.

Answer (score -1):

Although the question is for C#, here are 2 possibilities for C++ as the problem can arise there as well:
Either
`static_cast<B&>(d) = b;`
or without cast

```
B & b_of_d = d;
b_of_d = b;
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575249/how-to-assign-base-class-object-to-a-derived-class-object)

Comment: That answer is for C++. This question is about C#.

Comment: Ups, I missed that. I am going to not it in the answer.